# Confusion about 'thisArg' in array methods

Tags: javascript, this

I was learning about arrays methods and there's one thing I don't quite understand, possibly related to closures.

First things first though, here's the code snippet:

```js
let range = {
    minNumber: 20,
    maxNumber: 30,
    isValid(number) {
        return number >= this.minNumber && number < this.maxNumber;
    }
};
    
let numbers = [16, 23, 27,  30, 45];
    
let filteredNumbers = numbers.filter(range.isValid, range);
    
console.log(filteredNumbers.length); // 2
console.log(filteredNumbers[0]); // 23
console.log(filteredNumbers[1]); // 27
```

From what I understand by passing second argument we bind `this` to `range`, otherwise simply calling: `numbers.filter(range.isValid)` will make `this` undefined. Shouldn't it have access to `this` either way though, as we're "calling" `isValid` from `range` context by using `.` operator?

There is also a second approach that works:

```
numbers.filter(number => range.isValid(number))
```

What's going on here? Now it's able to pick up `this` from `range` object all of a sudden? Arrow functions have no `this` iirc, so it's not that.

Thanks for all the help in advance. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: When you call directly with the dot operator `foo.bar()` it picks up the context from the property access. When you pass a method as a callback it loses it: `someFn(foo.bar)`. The def of someFn is going to look something like this: `const someFn = f => f();` where it calls the argument (bound to f in this case) without the dot operator (i.e. no context). The fact that you're passing an arrow function is irrelevant, it's about when the property lookup occurs.

Comment: I moved your first approach into an executable snippet and it gives the desired result. Which I was expecting, because you did everything right.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that when you call

```
numbers.filter(range.isValid)
```

really what you are doing is passing the function by referrence or

```
numbers.filter(isValid(number) {
    return number >= this.minNumber && number < this.maxNumber;
  })
```

effectively the context is not transferred(e.g. maxNumber and minNumber are not set anywhere.)

when you do

```
numbers.filter(number => range.isValid(number))
```

it works because the => function does not establish a context so it gets the context from the definition of range in the current scope.

when you do

```
numbers.filter(range.isValid, range)
```

You are making use of the optional parameter to .filter described below(From W3C docs here:https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp)

> Optional. A value to be passed to the function to be used as its
>   "this" value. If this parameter is empty, the value "undefined" will
>   be passed as its "this" value